# Where is the database stored in surrealDB?

Tags: surrealdb

It doesn't say in the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

It really depends on how you run the database.

If you are using the cli and run the database via `surreal start`, the database runs **in-memory** per default. So the the data is **not stored persistently anywhere**.

You can manually provide a `path` to determine where the data is stored.

```
surreal start file://./surrealDB
```

Valid values for `path` are

- `memory` to store the data in-memory
- `file://<path>` to store the data in the specified path
- `tikv://<addr>` to store the data in a [TiKV](https://tikv.org/) database

---

- [Docs](https://surrealdb.com/docs/cli/start)

Comment: path is a dir not a file actually.

Answer (score 1):

[Tobias is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880717/8816585), I'll just add this [official link](https://surrealdb.com/docs/cli/start) for future-proofness.

The usage is indeed like this

```bash
surreal start [OPTIONS] [--] [path]
```

With `path` being optional and having `memory` as a default

> Can be one of `memory`, `file://<path>`, `tikv://<addr>`

```
<path>    Database path used for storing data [default: memory]
```

When starting the server, you'll also notice where it effectively runs by checking the console

[image]

---

That could also be useful to discover more useful params for the CLI like `-u` or `-p`.